# Queryset in django admin action is always empty

Tags: django, django-admin

I wrote an action that is supposed update a field in every record selected by the user according to [this document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-as-modeladmin-methods).
The problem is that `queryset` is always empty and thus, no changes take place.

```
def SendCommandAction(self, request, queryset):
   
    print(self._Command)
    commandStatus = {
                'Command':self._Command,
                'Fetched':False
            }
    print(queryset) #output from console: <QuerySet []>
    updated = queryset.update(Command_Status = commandStatus,)
    
    self.message_user(request, ngettext(
        '%d record was successfully updated.',
        '%d records were successfully updated.',
        updated,
    ) % updated, messages.SUCCESS)
```

After I select records and hit "Go" button this message appeares:

```
0 records were successfully updated.
```

Comment: Did you select items (with the checkboxes) before you triggered the action?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes I did. In fact I would get following error message if I didn't:" Items must be selected in order to perform actions on them. No items have been changed."

Comment: @mahsakhazaei did you find a problem? I am seeing the same behavior.

Comment: @UmairA. Unfortunately I still don't know what the problem was. I think I ended up getting the list of selected items in frontend and passing it to a view via ajax and handled the rest in that view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue and found that this method `options.response_action` is responsable for handling the action and the queryset it gets.

In my case, I'm using mongodb, and that method `response_action` is overwriting my queryset (the method is filtering by objects pks, but for mongodb you need to provide ObjectId instances to the filter function and django admin use just strings).

```
if not select_across:
    # Perform the action only on the selected objects
    queryset = queryset.filter(pk__in=selected)
    # `selected` here is a list of strings (and for mongodb should be bson.ObjectId)
    # that is the reason the queryset is empty in my case
```

I solved this creating a custom queryset class for my model and overwrite the filter function carefully to convert list of strings to list of bson.ObjectIDs only if the filter includes pk on it.

I think you need to debug this method and figure out what is happening in your case.

Good luck!
Luis.-